# To find shortest path

Tags: php, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, shortest-path

I have latitude and longitude of 50 node or more. Its not connected to each other. We will consider one node as start and end both.

I need to find the shortest path through these node that starts at 'start', ends at same point of start and passes through all of the nodes.

**Note:** Without using google maps api

Comment: Will an approximate distance between the points be sufficient? Is the distance for each pair of nodes explicitly given?

Comment: Could you brief the question? Is the graph directed? If so the shortest path cannot go through all the nodes.

Comment: @DineshAppavoo It is neither connected nor directed. I need to get solution for shortest path on that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is the [Euclidean TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean_TSP), which is NP-hard.

For very small inputs you can do it using brute force. For larger inputs, an approximation algorithm can be used (such as the one mentioned in the link, which guarantees a 2-approximation).

Comment: Could you please paste some piece of code here for reference? Because I am using TSP but its not giving the accurate result. I need to find Left/Right child for a node so it will connect the graph and get result on that basis.

Answer (score 0):

However you don't have sample data here, I think this may work:

```
names<-#read your nodes
rest<-list()
A<-list()
n=1
for  (i in 1:50){
    A<-get.all.shortest.paths(aracne_graph, names[i], names[i], mode = c("all"), weights=NULL)  
    rest[[n]]<-A$res
    n<-n+1
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate in detail?

Comment: Yes, names file includes all your nodes. Then you have a graph (e.g. here ARACNE_graph). So, you want to search for shortest paths from nodes in file names to the same node (names[i], names[i]).

Comment: I am getting your Idea in detail!